# importar uma variável de um arquivo _partial.scss e utilizá-la dentro de metodo em SASS

Tags: sass

Estou começando a trabalhar com SASS e estou tendo problemas com relação a estrutura de arquivos parciais. Pelo meu entendimento, fiz algo assim:

**_colors.scss**

```
$red: red;
$blue: blue
```

**_buttons.scss**

```
@import "colors";

button{
    background:$red;
    color:$blue;
}
```

**_style.scss**

```
@import "colors";
@import "buttons";
```

Só que usando isso o SASS está apresentando erro dizendo que eu não posso usar as variáveis já encontradas no arquivo _colors... como resolver?

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir esse erro, mas acho que dê pra solucionar não importando a **_colors.scss** na **_buttons.scss**.

Comment: eu importei a _colors.scss na _buttons.scss mas msemo assim não procedeu. minha solução foi reestruturar minha aplicação para que se encaixasse.

Comment: Eu fiz exatamente a mesma estrutura e não apresentou os erros que você comentou, pode ser algo intermitente ou algum bug

Comment: Pode ser possível resolver usando notação de ```!default``` nas variáveis globais.
```$red: red !default;```